# Updated user role inncorrect when using wp_get_current_user()

Tags: users, user-roles, cache

I ran into an issue with updating a user role, and then checking the current role somewhere later in the code.

After an entire day of debugging, and a night's rest, I figured it out by chance.

See the example below:

```
// Get current user object
$user = wp_get_current_user();  

// Set new role
$user->remove_role( 'member_pending' );
$user->add_role( 'member' );

// ... Later in another function

// Trying to get the updated role
$user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$role = $user->roles; // Returns "member_pending"

// Going through another hoop to get the role
$user = get_user_by('ID', wp_get_current_user()->ID);
$role = $user->roles; // Return the correct role "member"
```

I've also tried using `wp_cache_flush()` before using `wp_get_current_user()->roles`, but it still shows the incorrect role.

Like I said I already figured out how to "fix" this, but since I spent an entire day troubleshooting this issue, **I want to actually understand why it happens.**

Comment: `$user->roles` returns an array, not a single role.

Comment: @Jos Yes they both return an array, I just simplified the value in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled upon this same issue again, here's how to fix it.

For some reason, you cannot use `wp_get_current_user()`, as the data is not updated until a refresh happens.

So instead, you use `get_user_by()`.

```
// The updated current user
$updated_current_user = get_user_by( 'ID', wp_get_current_user()->ID );
```